# mvc5 create new select from query

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

this is the query :

```
var data = db.tableone.Where(a => a.type == 1).Select(u => new {id = u.id, type = u.type,newcolumnnotexistindatabase = "test"} );
return data.ToList();
```

while there is 5 column by the type of 1, it should show me in list

```
id, type -- newcolumnnotexistindatabase
1 , 1    --test
2 , 1    --test
3 , 1    --test
4 , 1    --test
5 , 1    --test
```

ERORR:

> can not implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<

Comment: Can you write full exception detail?

Comment: while returning it as < data.ToList()> not able Error is written

Comment: It looks like a problem with the return type of the method your query is a part of. Without full method **with its return type** you won't get any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, you can't return anonymous type. If return type of your function is `List<<AnyClass>>` , your linq query should be like this:

```
var data = db.tableone
     .Where(a => a.type == 1)
     .Select(u => new AnyClass
      {
        id = u.id, 
        type = u.type,
        newcolumnnotexistindatabase = "test"
      } );
 return data.ToList();
```

Comment: .Select(u => new AnyClass , --AnyClass-- is red line(error)

Comment: I wrote it for the example. **AnyClass** can be a class with any name you want. You should create a custom class with three properties(Id, Type, Newcolumnnotexistindatabase ).